# AJAX запрос CANCELED в Chrome (Drupal)

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal

С недавнего времени в chrome на сайте под управлением Drupal перестал работать ajax, смотрел в Edge - всё работает.

В отчете ничего не понятно, идет запрос и обрывается. Во вкладке сети хрома тоже ничего нету, даже initiator не показывает.

Этот же сайт есть на другом домене и без сертификата - там всё работает.

В чем проблема или это какой-то баг хрома  надо ждать его исправления?

Отчет из net-internals:

```
44859: URL_REQUEST
https://site18.ru/system/ajax
Start Time: 2020-06-03 10:42:18.618

t=3610 [st=  0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=435]
                 --> priority = "HIGHEST"
                 --> traffic_annotation = 63171670
                 --> url = "https://site18.ru/system/ajax"
t=3610 [st=  0]    NETWORK_DELEGATE_BEFORE_URL_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=3610 [st=  0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=435]
                   --> initiator = "https://site18.ru"
                   --> load_flags = 2 (BYPASS_CACHE)
                   --> method = "POST"
                   --> network_isolation_key = "https://site18.ru https://site18.ru"
                   --> privacy_mode = 0
                   --> site_for_cookies = "SiteForCookies: {scheme=https; registrable_domain=site18.ru}"
                   --> upload_id = "1591162526699741"
                   --> url = "https://site18.ru/system/ajax"
t=3611 [st=  1]      COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                     --> operation = "send"
                     --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=3611 [st=  1]      COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                     --> operation = "send"
                     --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=3611 [st=  1]      COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                     --> operation = "send"
                     --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=3611 [st=  1]      COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                     --> operation = "send"
                     --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=3611 [st=  1]      COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                     --> operation = "send"
                     --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=3611 [st=  1]      COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                     --> operation = "send"
                     --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=3611 [st=  1]      COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                     --> operation = "send"
                     --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=3611 [st=  1]      COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                     --> operation = "send"
                     --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=3611 [st=  1]      NETWORK_DELEGATE_BEFORE_START_TRANSACTION  [dt=0]
t=3612 [st=  2]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=3612 [st=  2]      HTTP_CACHE_DOOM_ENTRY  [dt=1]
                     --> net_error = -2 (ERR_FAILED)
t=3613 [st=  3]      HTTP_CACHE_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=3613 [st=  3]      HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=3613 [st=  3]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=1]
t=3613 [st=  3]        HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                       --> source_dependency = 44861 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=3614 [st=  4]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                       --> source_dependency = 44862 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=3614 [st=  4]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=3614 [st=  4]      UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT  [dt=0]
                     --> is_chunked = false
                     --> net_error = 0 (?)
                     --> total_size = 58829
t=3614 [st=  4]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=4]
t=3614 [st=  4]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_HTTP2_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                       --> :method: POST
                           :authority: site18.ru
                           :scheme: https
                           :path: /system/ajax
                           content-length: 58829
                           pragma: no-cache
                           cache-control: no-cache
                           origin: https://site18.ru
                           upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
                           dnt: 1
                           content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyVuz4TGI9KqF0by8
                           user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36
                           accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
                           sec-fetch-site: same-origin
                           sec-fetch-mode: navigate
                           sec-fetch-user: ?1
                           sec-fetch-dest: iframe
                           referer: https://site18.ru/node/add/product
                           accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                           accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
                           cookie: [269 bytes were stripped]
t=3615 [st=  5]        UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                       --> current_position = 0
t=3615 [st=  5]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 62684
t=3615 [st=  5]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 59832
t=3615 [st=  5]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 56980
t=3615 [st=  5]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 54128
t=3615 [st=  5]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 51276
t=3616 [st=  6]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2124
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 49152
t=3616 [st=  6]        UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                       --> current_position = 16384
t=3616 [st=  6]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 46300
t=3616 [st=  6]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 43448
t=3616 [st=  6]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 40596
t=3616 [st=  6]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 37744
t=3616 [st=  6]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 34892
t=3617 [st=  7]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2124
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 32768
t=3617 [st=  7]        UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                       --> current_position = 32768
t=3617 [st=  7]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 29916
t=3617 [st=  7]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 27064
t=3617 [st=  7]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 24212
t=3617 [st=  7]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 21360
t=3617 [st=  7]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 18508
t=3618 [st=  8]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2124
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 16384
t=3618 [st=  8]        UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                       --> current_position = 49152
t=3618 [st=  8]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 13532
t=3618 [st=  8]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 10680
t=3618 [st=  8]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -2852
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 7828
t=3618 [st=  8]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = -1121
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 6707
t=3618 [st=  8]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=3618 [st=  8]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=427]
t=3718 [st=108]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 2147418111
                       --> stream_id = 105
                       --> window_size = 2147424818
t=4045 [st=435]        CANCELLED
t=4045 [st=435] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема только в хроме, используем поиск для этого: [jQuery Form bug in Chromium-based browsers](https://www.drupal.org/node/3143016) - патчим или обновляем ядро. Так же и под [8](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3138421).

И пишем версию drupal!